# Error on Proxychains + Tor

Tags: tor, proxychains

I'm trying to connect through *Proxychains* and *nc* to a website but I get this error:

> myip.gelma.net:23: forward host lookup failed: Unknown host

Previously, I was reciving this error:

> |DNS-request| myip.gelma.net:23 
>   |D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-***********-<><>-OK
>   |DNS-response| myip.gelma.net:23 is 198.105.254.11
>   Segmentation fault

But commenting *proxy_dns* option on configuration file, I fixed this problem.

I tried a lot of things like change from *socks5* to *socks4*, play with *dinamic_chain* and *strict_chain* modes...

Now, I can't get the connection and I don't know why. How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a note, but socks4 does not support proxying DNS, so you will DNS leak with that. This is not a problem with socks4a or socks5. As for the segmentation fault, that just means that proxychains is very... poorly designed. It's an internal crash of the program. But unfortunately, without more information, I don't think anyone here can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix.

The problem was a bad network configuration of my virtual machine. When I recived this errors, the virtual machine network was configured as *Bridge*. When I changed from *Bridge* to *NAT*, this problem was solved.